# Cannot add a property to an object within a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, object

I am trying to insert a property to an object, here is the code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Question = () => {

  let active;

  const handleClick = (iconName) => {
    active = {};
    active[iconName] = true;
  };
  console.log(active.isHome);  // undefined

  return (
    <Link to='/'>
      <div
        className={`center ${active.isHome && 'active'}`}
        onClick={() => handleClick('isHome')}
      >
        <Home className='navItem' />
      </div>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default Question;
```

Above `active.isHome` returns `undefined`. It seems an unexpected behaviour to me. What can I do to insert `isHome: true` to the `active` object and why active is not assigned a value ?

Comment: `active` is not even assigned any value. What you should be getting is a TypeError.

Comment: why don't you use state?

Comment: React uses state; changes to state cause a re-render. Which in turn causes a functional component's function to run again. However `active` isn't part of the state, and Question is a function, not a class. So there's two problems here: the value of `active` will be lost each time the component re-renders, but this never happens because it doesn't have a state that changes.

Comment: Can you share a stackblitz link? Use state is something which can help

Comment: Everything will be answered here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 1):

Solution from what I understood from the question. Active class makes the background Green if " showHome.active?.isHome " is true and I have used optional chaining for ignoring the non-existence property inside active, when page loads initially

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const initialState = {
    active: {},
};

function App() {
    const [showHome, setShowHome] = useState(initialState);

    const bgChange = (iconName) => {
        let active = {};
        active[iconName] = true;
        setShowHome({ active });
    };

    console.log(showHome, '<>?', showHome.active?.isHome && 'active');
    return (
        <div className="body">
            <button onClick={() => bgChange('isHome')}>make active </button>
            <div className={`center ${showHome.active?.isHome && 'active'}`}>
                <h1>hi visible in Green</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```